# How do I setup Unreal Engine / Visual Studio to be able to code with JNI for Android?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, java-native-interface, unreal-engine4

In my project in Unreal Engine 4.25 want to use some native Android functionalities on the Oculus Quest by programming in C++ with JNI. However, I have problems with Visual Studio 2019 recognizing JNI specific code. I am able to launch an app to the Oculus Quest without adding JNI code, but when I want use `#include “Android/AndroidJNI.h”` Visual Studio complains it cannot find the source file.

I have tried installing the [Android Game Development Extension for Visual Studio](https://developer.android.com/games/agde) and followed their [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/games/agde/quickstart) on how to add Android as a target platform in the hopes this would fix the problem. However, this did not change anything. Code that I put within an `#if PLATFORM_ANDROID` block is greyed out, implying that Visual Studio does not correctly recognize I am targeting Android.

Does anybody know how to properly set up Unreal Engine and Visual Studio, so it can work with JNI?

Answer (score 0):

The header file is located at UE Engine code.

Ex) Program Files (x86)/Epic Games/UE_4.27/Engine/Source/Runtime/Launch/Public/Android/AndroidJNI.h

And you can include AndroidJNI.h adding "Launch" module in XXX.Build.cs

Ex)
PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new String[] {
"...",
"Launch",
});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).